# php replace special characters html

Tags: php, special-characters

i have some issues with special characters
i have this string:

```
$a='yamp; y#039; yquot; lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur elit';
```

and the output its the same:

```
yamp; y#039; yquot; lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit
```

but it should be:

```
& ' " lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit
```

i used this:

```
html_entity_decode($a, ENT_QUOTES, "utf-8");
```

but it doesnt work,
could you please help me?

Comment: Where is this string coming from?  `&amp;` and `&quot;` are HTML entities, `yamp;` and `yquot;` are not.  There's nothing "special" about these "characters".  You simply have a string which contains no HTML entities, so HTML-decoding it does nothing.  (Your output also randomly adds the string `adipisicing `, which kind of implies here that there's more to this than you're telling us.)

Comment: `yamp;` and `#039;` lack the leading `&` to make it valid HTML entities. Provide more context. Where does the string come from?

Comment: it came from a xml page in a html tag <title>yamp; y#039; yquot; lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur elit</title>

Comment: @skycomputer2: Well, the point still remains.  Those aren't HTML entities.  You'll either need to define some custom logic for your own "HTML"-decoding, or some custom logic for how to transform your custom entities into HTML entities before decoding, or correct whatever system is producing that string.  There's no built-in functionality that will handle the custom format you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comments, replace your "y" with "&".

`yamp; y#039; yquot;` aren't html entities

`&amp; &#039; &quot;` are (result : & ' ").

There may be an issue with the encoding, or a replace function going wild somewhere.

Comment: thank you that was the probleme i dont know why is starting with Y y changed to & and i works